# oh-my-zsh getting a command failed icon even when it doesn't

Tags: git, zsh, oh-my-zsh

> This happens only when I'm inside a `git repo`, see screenshot below
>   I am using this on ubuntu, with the gnome terminal.

I'm using the default robbyrussell theme
whenever i run any command i get a ✗ character, which means the previous command failed.
This happens even when the command worked perfectly and in fact I see symbol after every command I run.

What i noticed was that if the command failed, the ➜ character at the beginning of the prompt shows `red`. But the ✗ always stays there, any idea?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x means you have uncommitted changes in your GIT repo

(You can check by doing a git status)